# Apache NetBeans 12.6 palette in Palette Manager is not the same in windows palette

Tags: tomcat9, openjdk-11, netbeans-12

In the Palette Manager from tools -> palette:

[image: in the pallette manager from tools -> palette]

is different from:

Windows-> IDE tools-> Palette:

[image: windows-> IDE tools-> palette]

How would I make the actual palette from the windows IDE tools display the same from the tools palette manager.
This means that I want to display things in the palette to use such as the jstl forms as it was said to have already been included but yet not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled java run time environment 8 as apparently it was corrupted and downloaded javaee-endorsed-api-7.0.jar file to execute.

You can also go to

C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\javaee7-endorsed and paste the .jar file there to make it automatic.